# EXPRESS-G style arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to produce an EXPRESS-G diagram ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPRESS_(data_modeling_language)) or ISO 10303-11, Annex B).

I'm having difficulties producing the correct arrowhead for the inheritance relationship - it gets thicker together with the line itself, which is not wanted.

MWE: The circle at B should be of same size as the circle at C, with the line thickness staying unchanged.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw}]
    \node (a) {A};
    \node[left=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[right=of a] (c) {C};
    \draw[-o] (a) -- (c);
    \draw[-o,ultra thick] (a) -- (b); % how to only change line width, but not the arrowhead thickness?
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Produced result]

I've tried `line width` as an alternative to `ultra thick`, but to no avail.

Note: I know, that a tikzlibrary doing all this would be great, but I have not yet dived into the tikz library programming. Perhaps at some other time.

Comment: As a workaround you may try to place the arrowhead with no line to B-box and draw the thick line without arrowhead.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I split the definition, first drawing the thick line, then a line with a circle at the end. If I specify `open` circle, the thick line can still be seen; if I specify the circle `white` the line is covered, but the circle is gone as well. How to only change the fill color of the arrowhead but not its line color?

Comment: Ok, seems to be tricky. Then, drawing a circle as a node and putting all together seems possible, even if inconvenient.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that workaround - putting another circlar node at `node.east` or similar. But I assume there could already exist a better way :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `arrows.meta` you can actually add drawing instructions to the arrow tip, so you could define a new arrow tip with

```
circ/.tip={Circle[/tikz/thin, open, width=5pt, length=5pt]}
```

and use `-circ`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style={draw},
      circ/.tip={Circle[/tikz/thin, open, width=5pt, length=5pt]} % the default line width is actually thin
      ]
    \node (a) {A};
    \node[left=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[right=of a] (c) {C};
    \draw[-circ] (a) -- (c);
    \draw[-circ,ultra thick] (a) -- (b); % how to only change line width, but not the arrowhead thickness?
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It works.

Answer (score 2):

I was the developer of EXPRESS-G and wrote the `expressg` package for easy creation of EXPRESS-G, and other BLA (BoX Line Annotation) diagrams.

Unfortunatly, for some reason doing `texdoc expressg` returns `expeg.pdf` which shows samples of the package's output. For some reason the package is not in my computer's copy of TexLive but is available from https://ctan.org/pkg/expressg

Comment: It is a pleasure to get to know somebody that already did most of the heavy lifting! Care to join forces and provide a `tikzlibrary` for BLA / EXPRESS-G diagrams at some point?

I hope you don't mind that I don't change the correct answer, as it really solves the problem at hand, while your solves it on a more generic level.

Comment: @PjancMatuzl Thank you for the invitation but I am slowing down and my memory is not what it was. I have never used `tikz` and probably never will. If you want to use `expressg`-type ideas in `tikz` you are very welcome. --- GOM